# Setting attributes in ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to set the attribute based on some bool value in my view page like :

```
            @{
                object displayMode = (Model.PostCodeEnabled) ? null : new { disabled = "disabled", style = "width:200px;" };
                @Html.TextBox("PostalCode", "", displayMode)
            }
```

The above code is working fine, but if I want to apply width as 200px in both the case, then the following code is not working:

```
            @{
                object displayMode = (Model.PostCodeEnabled) ? new { style = "width:200px;" }: new { disabled = "disabled", style = "width:200px;" };
                @Html.TextBox("PostalCode", "", displayMode)
            }
```

Also I m little confused when to append @ symbol before the attribute that is the difference between new { disabled = "disabled"} & new { @disabled = "disabled"}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the @ signs - your problem is that you can't do implicit type conversion between two anonymous types.

This means, that you need to make a "proper" if statement, like this:

```
@{
    object displayMode = new { @disabled = "disabled", @style = "width:200px;" };

    if (Model.PostCodeEnabled)
    {
        displayMode = new { @style = "width:200px;" };
    }

    @Html.TextBox("PostalCode", "", displayMode)
}
```

Going back to the @ signs - you always need to include it when creating an anonymous type to use as HTML attributes.

Comment: Sorry, the above code also not working. At least can u let me know when to append @ symbol before the attribute that is the difference between new { disabled = "disabled"} & new { @disabled = "disabled"}.

Comment: Very True Martin. When I ve used proper if statements, it starts working. Still I m not sure about the @ part. As for me if I put @ before style attribute, its not working. But u ve used @ in the above code. I guess style is not an anonymous type?

Comment: You always need @. style, class, disabled have nothing to do with anonymous types. Anonymous types is the `new { }` part. The code I posted worked for me, so it should work for you too.

Comment: For me its working without @ symbol (May be as @ has additional meaning in MVC3, its not compulsory for HTML attributes) .            Anyways, my code is working now. Thanks.